# Segmentation fault in XServer

Tags: gnome, xorg, google-chrome, 15.10, asus

I have ASUS ZenBook UX305 with i7 CPU and integrated Intel GPU. My system (Ubuntu 15.10) recently started to go back to the login screen after some time active. It is caused by segfault in XServer. Here's the syslog fragment

```
Dec 29 22:44:45 marek-UX305LA org.ayatana.bamf[1365]: (bamfdaemon:1479): Gdk-WARNING **: bamfdaemon: Fatal IO error 11(Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne) on X server :0. 
Dec 29 22:44:45 marek-UX305LA org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1507]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11
(Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0" 
Dec 29 22:44:45 marek-UX305LA org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1507]: after 5593 requests (5593
known processed) with 0 events remaining. 
Dec 29 22:44:45 marek-UX305LA gnome-session[1489]: (unity-fallback-mount-helper:1670):
Gdk-WARNING **: unity-fallback-mount-helper: Fatal IO error 11 (Zasoby
chwilowo niedostępne) on X server :0. 
Dec 29 22:44:45 marek-UX305LA gnome-session[1489]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:1678):
Gdk-WARNING **: polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1: Fatal IO error 11
(Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne) on X server :0. 
Dec 29 22:44:45 marek-UX305LA org.freedesktop.Notifications[1365]: (notify-osd:2501):
Gdk-WARNING **: notify-osd: Fatal IO error 11 (Zasoby chwilowo
niedostępne) on X server :0.
```

and Xorg.0.log.old:

```
[   606.177] (EE) 
[   606.177] (EE) Backtrace:
[   606.177] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x5617f849f68e]
[   606.177] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x5617f82eb000+0x1b89f9) [0x5617f84a39f9]
[   606.177] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7ff040cf2000+0x352f0) [0x7ff040d272f0]
[   606.177] (EE) 
[   606.177] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[   606.177] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   606.177] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[   606.177] (EE) 
[   606.177] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   606.177] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   606.177] (EE) 
[   606.177] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[   606.277] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I also noticed that every time this happens, I'm using Chrome (I don't know if this is relevant though, because Chrome runs every Does anybody know what the problem could be? How could I debug it? Is it something I should report on bugs.launchpad.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by using workaround described here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1510970

to disable SNA.

I created /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf file with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
 Identifier "Card0"
 Driver "Intel"
 Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection
```

Comment: I was stuck in this issue for days and this finally solved it. Thanks! My bug: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259689/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-in-boot-segmentation-fault-xserver

Comment: Life saver. I installed Steam on Elementary OS Hera (which is Ubuntu Bionic essentially) and it screwed up something. Adding to Steam installation I had custom non apt Nvidia drivers (which were removed before applying this solution).