# unable to start lightdm after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, lightdm

I updated my ubuntu 16.04 machine a few days ago to 18.04. I had a few issues upgrading but I've delt with those. only one issue remain: no GUI. I've spent days troubleshooting and googling the issue but none of the fixes that i've found have fixed the issue. I'm not even sure what the root issue is.

anyway. Lightdm failes to start and I've tried changing to gdm3 but it also crashes. I have reinstalled them both and reinstalled my intel graphical drives (`xserver-xorg-video-intel`)

the only problem that i can see in the syslog is

`gpu-manager[6149]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic/updates/dkms`

and

```
systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
```

trying to restart lightdm (`sudo service lightdm start`) also fail.

Now, if I can't fix this issue. I do have a backup of my system but would it be possible to reinstall 18.04 completely without losing anything that is not system related?

I will provide the resul of any command below.

thank you for your help.

:EDIT1:

I've fixed it. kind of...

I looked into the /var/log/Xorg.0.log file and found this:

```
[    14.462] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    14.462] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    14.462] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    14.462] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[    14.462] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    14.462] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[    14.462] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    14.462] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[    14.464] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    14.464]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    14.464]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    14.464] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[    14.476] (EE)
[    14.476] (EE) Backtrace:
[    14.476] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x55d55f6cb8ad]
[    14.476] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55d55f513000+0x1bc649) [0x55d55f6cf649]
[    14.476] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f5e685e9000+0x12890) [0x7f5e685fb890]
[    14.476] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f5e681f8000+0xb1646) [0x7f5e682a9646]
[    14.476] (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__strdup+0xe) [0x7f5e682959ae]
[    14.476] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7f5e61352000+0x211db) [0x7f5e613731db]
[    14.476] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7f5e61352000+0x18d5d) [0x7f5e6136ad5d]
[    14.476] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7f5e61352000+0x156be) [0x7f5e613676be]
[    14.476] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7f5e61352000+0x15705) [0x7f5e61367705]
[    14.476] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (eglInitialize+0x138) [0x7f5e61361d28]
[    14.476] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (glamor_egl_init+0x10b) [0x7f5e63acfc9b]
[    14.476] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (0x7f5e6430d000+0x9d89) [0x7f5e64316d89]
[    14.476] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0xc08) [0x55d55f5ac268]
[    14.476] (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55d55f513000+0x56cd3) [0x55d55f569cd3]
[    14.476] (EE) 14: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f5e68219b97]
[    14.476] (EE) 15: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x55d55f553b8a]
[    14.476] (EE)
[    14.476] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[    14.476] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    14.476] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    14.476] (EE)
```

I googled it and found a workaround here: [Segmentation fault in XServer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714771/segmentation-fault-in-xserver)

so the login screen gets revealed propperly now, but I'm currently stuck in a login loop. but that is another issue.

```
ls -al /home/karl/.*author*
-rwx------ 1 karl karl 55770 okt 11 01:56 /home/karl/.ICEauthority
-rwx------ 1 karl karl  9570 dec  9  2017 /home/karl/.ICEauthority.backup.20171209
-rw------- 1 karl karl    54 okt 11 01:57 /home/karl/.Xauthority
-rw------- 1 karl karl    54 okt 11 00:16 /home/karl/.Xauthority.bak
-rw------- 1 karl karl    54 okt 11 01:06 /home/karl/.Xauthority.bakk
-rwx------ 1 karl karl    54 okt
```

8 02:36 /home/karl/.Xauthority.old

```
ls -al /var/lib/dkms
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 okt 11 02:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 86 root root 4096 okt 11 02:06 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    6 aug 31  2016 dkms_dbversion
```

and

```
ls -al /usr/src
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 okt  5 14:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 feb 15  2017 ..
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 dec  4  2017 linux-headers-4.10.0-40
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 dec  4  2017 linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 okt  7 22:56 linux-headers-4.15.0-34
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 okt  7 22:56 linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 okt  7 22:57 linux-headers-4.15.0-36
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 okt  7 22:57 linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 feb 15  2017 linux-headers-4.8.0-36
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 feb 15  2017 linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic
```

this is the error I get when trying to start a gnome shell.

```
sudo gnome-shell gnome
gnome-shell: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmutter-2.so.0: undefined symbol: wl_global_get_interface
```

Trying to reinstall libmutter-2-0:

```
karl@Bulbasaur:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall libmutter-2-0
Läser paketlistor… Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd
Läser tillståndsinformation… Färdig
0 att uppgradera, 0 att nyinstallera, 1 att installera om, 0 att ta bort och 41 att inte uppgradera.
Behöver hämta 1 205 kB arkiv.
Efter denna åtgärd kommer ytterligare 0 B utrymme användas på disken.
Läs:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libmutter-2-0 amd64 3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1 [1 205 kB]
Hämtade 1 205 kB på 0s (2 827 kB/s)
(Läser databasen ... 220135 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Förbereder att packa upp .../libmutter-2-0_3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Packar upp libmutter-2-0:amd64 (3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1) över (3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Ställer in libmutter-2-0:amd64 (3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Hanterar utlösare för libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSegFault.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcprofile.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libminiupnpc.so.10 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3 is not a symbolic link
```

sudo ldconfig
    sudo] lösenord för karl:
    /sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSegFault.so är inte en symbolisk länk

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so är inte en symbolisk länk

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcprofile.so är inte en symbolisk länk

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so är inte en symbolisk länk

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetapi.so.0 är inte en symbolisk länk

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9 är inte en symbolisk länk

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so är in  GNU nano 2.9.3       /var/tmp/locale.XXf0eGrt
```

"är inte en symbolisk länk" means "is not a symbolic link"

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 uses gdm (the `gdm3` package) instead of lightdm.

Comment: Is your an older computer? What video hardware do you have? I have an idea.

Comment: @heynnema it's an i7 gen2. no gpu card. but I have fixed it, the issue now is the login loop.

Comment: What is the output of `dkms status` and `ls -al /home/your_username/.*author*`? Boot into recovery mode if you have to.

Comment: @heynnema I didn't have dkms installed and once i installed the package the command gave no output. and yes everything in my home folder is owned by me and is in my group, I've ran `sudo chmod username:username -R .`

Comment: Show me the output of my previous `ls` command. What's the output of `ls -al /var/lib/dkms` and `ls -al /usr/src`? Edit that output into your question, not in the comments, please. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema done.

Comment: Doing a recursive chown (you wrote chmod) can cause all kinds of problems. Your .ICEauthority* files show rwx, so you should try a `sudo chmod 600 /home/karl/.ICEauthority*` and then try to login again.

Comment: @heynnema I did that but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Try `sudo ldconfig` and see if that fixes things.

Comment: @heynnema same as when I tried to reinstall it libmutter

Comment: Maybe a 18.04.1 reinstall, and deselect the "format" partition option.

Comment: @heynnema yeah thats the plan. Will that remove/reset everything to default? I.e will I need to reconfigure the fstab or my /opt programs or anything like that? I'm a bit unsure what the reinstall will do. I have a backup of everything but I'd rather not mess with any of that unless I have to.

Comment: @KarlBlixt yes, there will be some work to do. If you've customized stuff, copy them off to a flash drive, so if you need to, you can put them back... although it's probably better just to re-edit the fresh files.