# How to prevent random logouts on Nvidia GeForce GPU (Nouveau)?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, systemd, crash, nouveau

I recently replaced my old AMD Radeon video card with a GeForce GTX 650 in a PC with an AMD CPU.

The card seems to work fine, however, since the replacement, Xubuntu 18.04 gets  seemingly random logouts every couple of hours. The screens turn black and a few seconds later, I find myself back at the greeter, having to log back in with all programs closed/crashed.

This did not happen once before and this also happened on a live system (Ubuntu MATE), so I assume the video card is definitely the culprit in the equation.

The error log apparently shows some problems with `bamfdaemon` at the timecode of the logout:

```
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE bamfdaemon[2064]: bamfdaemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE pulseaudio[1649]: X connection to :0.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE at-spi-bus-launcher[1746]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE [2027]: xfce4-notifyd: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE dbus-daemon[1673]: [session uid=1000 pid=1673] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.38' (uid=1000 pid=1941 comm="/usr/lib/tracker/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Stopped BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Starting BAMF Application Matcher Framework...
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE dbus-daemon[1673]: [session uid=1000 pid=1673] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 1541 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 1652 (gnome-keyring-d) with signal SIGTERM.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 1736 (ssh-agent) with signal SIGTERM.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 1931 (applet.py) with signal SIGTERM.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 1933 (zeitgeist-datah) with signal SIGTERM.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 1941 (tracker-miner-f) with signal SIGTERM.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: Stopping Session c2 of user.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26319]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26319]: cannot open display: :0
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Failed to start BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1611]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Succeeded.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: Stopped Session c2 of user.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE dbus-daemon[1040]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.15' (uid=0 pid=1057 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE dbus-daemon[1040]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: resolvconf-pull-resolved.service: Succeeded.
May 18 00:09:48 MACHINE systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: pulseaudio.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Stopped Sound Service.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Starting Sound Service...
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Stopped BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Starting BAMF Application Matcher Framework...
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Started Sound Service.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26410]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26410]: cannot open display: :0
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Failed to start BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Stopped BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Starting BAMF Application Matcher Framework...
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26439]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26439]: cannot open display: :0
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Failed to start BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 112.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/112...
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1]: Started User Runtime Directory /run/user/112.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 112...
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Reached target Timers.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Listening on debconf communication socket.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Reached target Paths.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Listening on Sound System.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Reached target Sockets.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Reached target Basic System.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 112.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Starting Sound Service...
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of user lightdm.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Stopped BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:49 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Starting BAMF Application Matcher Framework...
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26474]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26474]: cannot open display: :0
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Failed to start BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE dbus-daemon[26477]: [session uid=112 pid=26477] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE dbus-daemon[26477]: [session uid=112 pid=26477] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-spi-dbus-bus.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=112 pid=26473 comm="/usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter " label="unconfined")
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE dbus-daemon[26477]: [session uid=112 pid=26477] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Started Accessibility services bus.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE dbus-daemon[26477]: [session uid=112 pid=26477] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service' requested by ':1.3' (uid=112 pid=26473 comm="/usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter " label="unconfined")
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE dbus-daemon[26477]: [session uid=112 pid=26477] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Stopped BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Starting BAMF Application Matcher Framework...
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26496]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE bamfdaemon[26496]: cannot open display: :0
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Failed to start BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Stopped BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: bamfdaemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[1611]: Failed to start BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE rtkit-daemon[1525]: Successfully made thread 26466 of process 26466 owned by '112' high priority at nice level -11.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE rtkit-daemon[1525]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 2 users.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE rtkit-daemon[1525]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 2 users.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE rtkit-daemon[1525]: Successfully made thread 26511 of process 26466 owned by '112' RT at priority 5.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE rtkit-daemon[1525]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 2 users.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Started Sound Service.
May 18 00:09:50 MACHINE systemd[26450]: Reached target Main User Target.
```

Is there anything that can be done about this or might this be an issue with the hardware itself? (Currently using Xubuntu 18.04 on Kernel 5.3)

Comment: I added it, I'm using Xubuntu 18.04, Kernel 5.3.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/714771/segmentation-fault-in-xserver seems related. You might want to give that answer a try :)

Comment: @Rinzwind, I already found this question, but it appears to be related to the Intel-driver. I am using an Nvidia card, in fact, I don't even have an Intel CPU, how should I configure the `sna`-option in Nouveau? I wasn't able to find anything on that.